# Why i get an error "list index out of range" and how to fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, for-loop, gmail

I need my bot to check for new gmail messages from tradingview and, depending on the Subject, perform actions in if

```
import email, imaplib
import datetime, time
import logging

volume = "0.1"
user = 'xxxxx@gmail.com'
password = 'xxxxxxx'
imap_url = 'imap.gmail.com'

def auth(user,password,imap_url):
    m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_url)
    m.login(user,password)
    return m

def readmail(volume):
    time.sleep(1.5)
    m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
    m = auth(user,password,imap_url)
    m.select('INBOX')
    resp, items = m.search(None,
                           "NOT SEEN FROM tradingview")
    items = items[0].split()
    for emailid in items:
        resp, data = m.fetch(emailid,
                             "(RFC822)")
        email_body = data[0][1]
        mail = email.message_from_bytes(email_body)
        ts = time.time()
        st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        try:
            pair = mail['Subject'].split()[2]
            if mail['Subject'].split()[3] == "Buy":
                m.store(emailid, '+FLAGS', '\Seen')
                print(st + ' \x1b[6;30;42m' + 'Buy')
                logging.info(st + ' Buy')
            if mail['Subject'].split()[3] == "Sell":
                m.store(emailid, '+FLAGS', '\Seen')
                print(st + ' \x1b[6;30;41m' + 'Sell')
                logging.info(st + ' Sell')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            logging.info(e)

while True:
    try:
        readmail(volume)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        logging.info(e)
```

Expected:

print(st + ' \x1b[6;30;42m' + 'Buy') or print(st + ' \x1b[6;30;42m' + 'Sell')

Actual:

list index out of range

But for some reason, my bot reads new messages
m.store(emailid, '+FLAGS', '\Seen')
and makes a "read" mark

Comment: Can you share your full stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Great question!  I have run into this many times, so I can make some helpful conclusions.  Whenever your error is 'List Index out of Range', 95% of the time it is the list not containing as many values as you think.  I do see you are a newer StackOverflow member.  Welcome to the community!  If you are unfamiliar with slightly more advanced Python list concepts, allow me to explain.

Everything in a list has a index value.  It begins at zero, and goes up by one per list item, regardless of the data type inside the list.

Example:

```
lista= ['This', 'Is', 'A', 'List!']
```

The above has a low index of 0, and the last index is 3.
A breakdown:

```
lista= ['This', 'Is', 'A', 'List!']
       index 0   1     2    index 3
```

What is most likely happening is you have a list that has smaller index that listed in your code later on.  So maybe you are calling index `[4]` in the above list.  This will return an error, because there is no fourth index.  It is....out of range!  That is what your error code means!

You can easily check how long your list is with the len() casting method.  This will tell you how many indexes are in your list.  If I were to run the follwing snippet:

`len(lista)`

I would get:

`4`

This shows the four indexes.  If you want to know the largest index, or you top one, minus the result of the above snippet by 1:

`print(len(lista)-1)`

Which returns:

`3`

Which is your top index.  So check the size of your lists, and I am confident your problems will be solved if you call the right indexes.  Also, make sure the data is getting added to the list correctly, or it will certainly not be there!  Good luck in all your coding in the future, and welcome to the Stack Exchange community!

`Ethan J.`